# How do I create a branched AlexNet in PyTorch?

Tags: machine-learning, pytorch

I am attempting to create a near identical model architecture to AlexNet, except each channel (Red, Green, and Blue) are disconnected by their own branch and are all concatenated at the end for the classifier.

[Similar architecture to this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BB8Nz.png)

### The base network:

```
class AlexNet(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, num_classes: int = 1000, dropout: float = 0.5) -> None:
        super().__init__()
        _log_api_usage_once(self)
        self.features = nn.Sequential(
            nn.Conv2d(3, 64, kernel_size=11, stride=4, padding=2),
            nn.ReLU(inplace=True),
            nn.MaxPool2d(kernel_size=3, stride=2),
            nn.Conv2d(64, 192, kernel_size=5, padding=2),
            nn.ReLU(inplace=True),
            nn.MaxPool2d(kernel_size=3, stride=2),
            nn.Conv2d(192, 384, kernel_size=3, padding=1),
            nn.ReLU(inplace=True),
            nn.Conv2d(384, 256, kernel_size=3, padding=1),
            nn.ReLU(inplace=True),
            nn.Conv2d(256, 256, kernel_size=3, padding=1),
            nn.ReLU(inplace=True),
            nn.MaxPool2d(kernel_size=3, stride=2),
        )
        self.avgpool = nn.AdaptiveAvgPool2d((6, 6))
        self.classifier = nn.Sequential(
            nn.Dropout(p=dropout),
            nn.Linear(256 * 6 * 6, 4096),
            nn.ReLU(inplace=True),
            nn.Dropout(p=dropout),
            nn.Linear(4096, 4096),
            nn.ReLU(inplace=True),
            nn.Linear(4096, num_classes),
        )

    def forward(self, x: torch.Tensor) -> torch.Tensor:
        x = self.features(x)
        x = self.avgpool(x)
        x = torch.flatten(x, 1)
        x = self.classifier(x)
        return x
```

### Training

```
def train_epoch(self, epoch, total):
    self.model.train()
   
    for batch_idx, (features, targets) in enumerate(self.train_loader):
        features = features.to(self.device)
        targets = targets.to(self.device)

        logits = self.model(features)

        loss = self.loss_func(logits, targets)
      
        self.optimizer.zero_grad()
        loss.backward()
        self.optimizer.step()
```

I would like to have each channel be belong to its own feature extraction, but combine to classify.

```
red = features[:,0:1,:,:] 
green = features[:,1:2,:,:]
blue = features[:,2:3,:,:]
logits = self.model([r,g,b])
```

I have seen people use groups but I am not sure how to implement it fully.
Any help is greatly appreciated

Comment: Do you want to share the weights between the channels, or use independent weights?

Comment: Independent weights

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since each branch/head would take an image with one channel you could start by just replacing the `3` in the first CNN layer with `1`:

```py
nn.Conv2d(1, 64, kernel_size=11, stride=4, padding=2),
```

Now you can send the three single-channeled images through the `self.features` layers and concat them before passing them to the `self.classifier` layers:

```py
import torch
import torch.nn as nn


class AlexNet(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, num_classes: int=1000, dropout: float=0.5) -> None:
        super().__init__()

        self.features = nn.Sequential(
            nn.Conv2d(1, 64, kernel_size=11, stride=4, padding=2),
            nn.ReLU(inplace=True),
            nn.MaxPool2d(kernel_size=3, stride=2),
            nn.Conv2d(64, 192, kernel_size=5, padding=2),
            nn.ReLU(inplace=True),
            nn.MaxPool2d(kernel_size=3, stride=2),
            nn.Conv2d(192, 384, kernel_size=3, padding=1),
            nn.ReLU(inplace=True),
            nn.Conv2d(384, 256, kernel_size=3, padding=1),
            nn.ReLU(inplace=True),
            nn.Conv2d(256, 256, kernel_size=3, padding=1),
            nn.ReLU(inplace=True),
            nn.MaxPool2d(kernel_size=3, stride=2),
        )
        self.avgpool = nn.AdaptiveAvgPool2d((3, 3))
        self.classifier = nn.Sequential(
            nn.Dropout(p=dropout),
            nn.Linear(6912, 4096),
            nn.ReLU(inplace=True),
            nn.Dropout(p=dropout),
            nn.Linear(4096, 4096),
            nn.ReLU(inplace=True),
            nn.Linear(4096, num_classes),
        )

    def forward(self, x_r: torch.Tensor, x_g: torch.Tensor, x_b: torch.Tensor) -> torch.Tensor:
        x_r = self.features(x_r)
        x_r = torch.flatten(self.avgpool(x_r), 1)

        x_g = self.features(x_g)
        x_g = torch.flatten(self.avgpool(x_g), 1)

        x_b = self.features(x_b)
        x_b = torch.flatten(self.avgpool(x_b), 1)

        x = torch.concat((x_r, x_g, x_b), -1)

        x = self.classifier(x)
        return x


model = AlexNet()
img = torch.rand(1, 3, 256, 256)
img_r = torch.rand(1, 1, 256, 256)
img_g = torch.rand(1, 1, 256, 256)
img_b = torch.rand(1, 1, 256, 256)

output = model(img_r, img_g, img_b)
```

Note that I changed `self.avgpool = nn.AdaptiveAvgPool2d((6, 6))` to `self.avgpool = nn.AdaptiveAvgPool2d((3, 3))` because the output size of the flattened branches was really big (`9216`). Now it is `2304` and by concatinating them you get a tensor of size `6912`. Hope this helps :)

Comment: Thank you very much, is there a difference between doing it like this and using groups instead?